# Pooling package installs in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I am trying to set up a system with multiple roles (e.g., webserver, database-server, mailserver etc.)

Each of the roles requires the installation of some software packages defined as their own task in the `main.yml` for each role.

Does **ansible** have a way to detect (or explicitly state it in a task) that in a certain play there will be multiple package installs and allow batching them together and skipping the later install steps?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: No, and you probably don't actually want this either. It would make manual rollbacks (e.g. `yum history undo ...` more difficult or impossible, for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to tag the installation tasks and install the packages as a 1st step:

```
ansible-playbook webserver.yml -t install_packages
ansible-playbook dbserver.yml -t install_packages
ansible-playbook mailserver.yml -t install_packages
```

Then run the plays:

```
ansible-playbook webserver.yml
ansible-playbook dbserver.yml
ansible-playbook mailserver.yml
```

If you want to speed-up the plays and conditionally skip the installations you might want to create and set a variable for this purpose (when: skip_install).

```
ansible-playbook -e skip_install=True ...
```

Comment: Since it is not a direct capability and as @Michael Hampton points out is probably not desirable, I'll acceppt this approximation as an answer